# Не работает if в javascript

Tags: javascript

Если ввести в var n 121, а в var s 2 или числа 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, то `document.write` не выполняется, но, например, ввести в var s 1, то `document.write` выполнится. В чем причина, подскажите?

```
var n = prompt("Введите число", "");
var s = prompt("Угадайте число", "");
if (n > s) 
    document.write("n больше s");
```

Comment: Что за неведомую чушь вы написали? Вы можете нормально связать хотя бы два слова?

Comment: ну если в переменную n ввести 121 а в переменную s 2 то  document.write("n больше s"); не выполнится !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию parseInt которая преобразует первый аргумент в число, т.е:

```
var n = prompt('Введите число', '');
var s = prompt('Угадайте число', '');
if (parseInt(n) > parseInt(s))
{
    document.write('n больше s');
}
```

Так должно работать.

Comment: лучше `Number(x)`

Comment: почему это?

Comment: karmadro4 - ничем не лучше

Comment: Все нормально работает свою ошибку понял!
var n = prompt("Введите число","");
n=parseInt(n);
var s = prompt("Угадайте число","");
s=parseInt(s);
if(n>s)
 { 
   document.write("больше");
 }

Comment: @Spectre, хотя бы потому, что в JS нет типов Int или Floar, а есть общий тип Number. А вообще посмотрите в документацию, поведение этих функций довольно сильно различается.

Comment: я не спорю, можно даже `+"123"` использовать, но по-моему parseInt наиболее адекватно преобразовывает данные к числовому значению, хоть и медленнее других способов

Comment: @Spectre, 

> +"123"

Это прямо обфускация какая-то :-) В то время, как Number семантично преобразовывает вариант к числу.
Кстати, в чем заключается прибавка адекватности при выборе parseInt вместо Number? @AlexWindHope, тот же вопрос и вам.

Comment: да об этом можно долго спорить, о том, что лучше: получить ноль или NaN; о том как эти функции будут вести себя в следующей спецификации и т.п. я просто высказал своё специфическое мнение по поводу "адекватности"

Comment: @Spectre, 

> как эти функции будут вести себя в следующей спецификации

Тащемта поведение стандартизовано. И насчет 0 вы сочиняете. Давайте подойдем так: `parseInt('010') == parseInt('8A')` :-)

Comment: вы хотели меня этим удивить? удивили, я ожидал нечто такое `parseInt("09") == Number("09")`. второй параметр ещё никто не отменял

P.S. скоро лимит комментариев кончится

Comment: @karmadro4 - parseInt функция предназначенная для преобразования строки в int значение, к тому-же - прекрасно работает с значениями вида: 1,1231231299 и т.д.

Number(var) - **не** javascript'овый стиль.

Встречный вопрос - если вы утверждаете что Ваш вариант лучше - обоснуйте пожалуйста хоть как-то, сплошное голословие (тонкий тролинг, как хотите). Заметьте я не писал что одно лучше другого, вы же написали и не подкрепили ровным счетом ничем.

PS: не забываем, что в java, для таких целей, **обычно**, тоже используется parseInt (если быть точным - Integer.parseInt)

Comment: @karmadro4 - мне не интересно что-либо вам доказывать, нравится писать так как вы пишите - пишите, мне все-равно. Еще раз напомню - **я не утверждал что одно лучше другого**, будьте так добры - обратите внимание на это предложение. Ничем не лучше - не означает что так делать хуже, так что не надо пожалуйста о "невнимательности", ок?

PS: по поводу "толкать речь" - только после вас, не я эту кашу заварил

Comment: @karmadro4 - минус за преобразование в ответ текста который не иметтникакого отношения к вопросу.

Я согласен - я ничего не понимаю и не разбираюсь, будьте так добры, распишите пожалуйста Вашу точку зрения  так, что-бы я и остальные смогли разобраться и принять ваши "неоспоримые" религиозные взгляды.

На данный момент дискуссия абсолютно не о чем. Примерно как спор буддиста и христианина о том, чье верование верно, только я, в отличии от вас - не утверждаю что одно вернее другого, а второе хуже, лишь считаю что **оба варианта имеют право на существование**.

Answer (score 6):

```js
var n = +prompt("Введите число", "");
var s = +prompt("Угадайте число", "");

if (n > s) {
  document.write("n больше s");
}
```